# How to determine whether code is running during a unit test run

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I need to have some kind of if statement to ignore certain bits of code e.g. pop dialog if the coding is being run as part of a unit test.

Does anyone have any idea have to do this - similar to debug?

Comment: I removed my answer (it doesn't work like @Sulthan said) but I'd like to mention the note I had in it : That may not be a good thing, as you will have different behavior in your test. The closer your test code is from the real code, the better. If you can, I would recommend finding other ways (dismissing the pop dialog by code for instance).

Comment: @Julien I agree. I am trying to use unit tests only for business code and UI Automation for everything else. If business code is correctly separated from UI, it works very well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prefer runtime solution, not a one based on preprocessor:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        BOOL tests = NO;

        for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
            NSString* argument = [NSString stringWithCString:argv[i] encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

            if ([argument isEqualToString:@"-SenTest"]) {
                tests = YES;
                break;
            }
        }

       if (tests) {
           //save YES to a global variable and use it whenewer you want
       }

       UIApplicationMain(...)

    }
}
```

I am actually using this to have a different `UIApplicationDelegate` when unit tests are run, so no UI code (DB opening, notifications started etc) collides with my test cases.

Comment: @TheLearner Whenewer you are running SenTests (OCUnit), there must be the `-SenTest` argument, usually with next parameter specifying `All` or the individual test cases to be run. `NSLog` the arguments and you will see that I am right.